# jQuery getting attribute then adding class when clicking div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add functionality to an already built javascript slider. I am trying to add in images of the videos that people can click to bring them to the proper video in the slide. I am trying to accomplish this with jQuery. I would like to know how to get the attribute of the divs inside of div.navBulletsWrapper. My code at the moment seems to change all the divs to rel="0" instead of getting the rel value and setting the class accordingly. Thanks for any help.

HTML:

```
<div class="video-thumbnail">
    <a id="video-thumbnail1">
       <img src="/_images/VideoImages/btn_FreeConsultation.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This is being created dynamically by the slider javascript:

```
<div class="navBulletsWrapper">
    <div class="active" rel="0"> … </div>
    <div rel="1"> … </div>
    <div rel="2"> … </div>
    <div rel="3"> … </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#video-thumbnail1').click(function(){
        $('div.navBulletsWrapper div').attr("rel", "0").addClass("active");
    });

});
```

live website in case you want to see full code: http://www.hazeltonlawgroup.com

Comment: Not sure to fully understand your question, but tell me if i am wrong, you want to select the `div` with the attribute `rel=0` and add the class to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a div according to its attribute, you have to do it with selector:

```
$('div.navBulletsWrapper div[rel="0"]').addClass('active') ;
```

If you want to remove class from the others div:

```
$('div.navBulletsWrapper div:not([rel="0"])').removeClass('active')
```

Comment: This was actually a very good answer as it is not what I asked, but I still did need to remove instances of the class from other divs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.navBulletsWrapper div').attr("rel", "0")
```

This **sets** all the child div's with attribute `rel="0" .`

If you looking to target that div.. then you selector should somewhat look in these lines.

```
$('div.navBulletsWrapper').find("[rel='0']").addClass("active");
```

Comment: there should be a . before the find function

Answer (score 1):

With the attar method you can set and get an attribute.

```
el.attr('attribute',value')
```

set the attribute.

```
el.attr('attribute')
```

get the attribute value.

Just change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#video-thumbnail1').click(function(){
        $('div.navBulletsWrapper div[rel='+index+']').addClass("active");
    });

});
```

Where *index* is the element which you want to add the 'active' class

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$('div.navBulletsWrapper div').filter("[rel=0]").addClass("active");
```

or

```
$('div.navBulletsWrapper').find("div[rel=0]").addClass("active");
```